# Typescript : combine mappable indexable type and property both with the same value type in an interface

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to combine a mappable indexable type with a property of the same value type in an interface.

Here is an example where this would be useful.

```
export type SupportedLanguagesUnion = 'fr' | 'es';

export interface Translation {
    [word: string]: {
        default: string;
        [language in SupportedLanguagesUnion]?: string;
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Translation } from './example';

const translationDictionary: Translation = {
    hello: {
        default: 'hello',
        fr: 'bonjour',
        es: 'hola'
    }
};
```

This interface would ensure that there is no unsupported languages but always a default value.

Unfortunately this code isn't valid typescript. I guess the problem lies in the conflict between default and language both having the same value type.

For the moment I have to  replace the interface with the less secure

```
export interface Translation {
    [word: string]: {
        default: string;
        [language: string]: string;
    }
}
```

that would accept the following code

```
const translationDictionary: Translation = {
    hello: {
        default: "hello",
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};
```

I could also add `'default'` as a value in the `SupportedLanguagesUnion` but then it would become optional.

Is there a way to write this interface in order to keep both checks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type (for the languages in `SupportedLanguagesUnion`) in an intersection (`&`) with the a type that has the extra properties you require:

```
export type SupportedLanguagesUnion = 'fr' | 'es';

export interface Translation {
    [word: string]: {
        default: string;
    } & {
        [language in SupportedLanguagesUnion]?: string;
    }
}

const translationDictionary: Translation = {
    hello: {
        default: 'hello',
        fr: 'bonjour',
        es: 'hola'
    }
};
```